# Как сделать перенос строки в окне PowerShell?

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, powershell

По SSH через PowerShell подключаюсь к VDS.

Если что-то не влазит в размер окна при выводе, то могу посмотреть через стрелки.

Но если смотреть журнал **journalctl** работы сервиса, то иногда в печати формируется длинная строка, которую невозможно посмотреть через  стрелки.

Уменьшать шрифт через свойства - такая себе идея.

Может есть какой-то аргумент для переноса строки, если он не влазит в окно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй добавить строку перед journalctl:

```
SYSTEMD_LESS=FRXMK journalctl
```

Comment: ¿Что делает эта строка? ¿Что такое `FRXMK`?

Comment: Переносит строки вывода journalctl, просто магия.

Comment: ничего не записывает, т.е. на один раз